# Wordpress - how to work with automatic resized images

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm developing a theme for one of my clients.

The custom theme uses a js library that reads into a specific folder and then generates the gallery using the picture found in this folder.

My idea was to use the uploads folder so that my client can manage the gallery on his own without my intervention.

Wordpress automatically saves multiple pictures in this folder, but that's quite easy to solve:

- Change upload into subfolders option
- Changed all the sizes to 0 to prevent resizing.

This two options almost work, I say almost because I still have a copy saved in my folder with dimensions 768x510.

Again, i can close an eye on this, because i actually had another idea...

The js library i want to use, allows my to create a subfolder called Thumbnails and in this folder add the same pictures but in a small format to help with loading time, and i'd like to do so.

So here comes my real question (sorry for the long intro)
Is it possible to write a custom function or is there any plugin that allows me to say:

"right, here's a picture, now crop it with the dimension I tell you (just one), don't rename it (do not append the size at the end) and then move it into this folder (Thumbnails)"

I don't have any code yet, as I'm asking for the right direction and, most of all, if it's even possible!

thanks for any suggestion

Comment: Yes, definitly possible! `php` has some good functions for that, I'll post a full answer shortly.

Comment: thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is definitly possible. You can get the files by [`readdir`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php), then you can pass them through something like this.

Here is an *example* of a `php` function resizing. **Note:** It is just some function I had laying around.

```
function resize($path,$x1,$y,$w,$h,$x2,$y2){
        $x = getimagesize($path);            
        switch ($x['mime']) {
            case "image/gif":
                $img = imagecreatefromgif($path);
            break;
            case "image/jpeg":
                $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($path);
            break;
            case "image/png":
                $img = imagecreatefrompng($path);
            break;
       }
        $width  = imagesx($img); 
        $height = imagesy($img); 
        $scalerw = ($width / $x2);
        $scalerh = ($height / $y2);

        $w = $w * 2;
        $h = $h *2;
        $img_base = imagecreatetruecolor($w,$h);
        $x1 = $x1 * $scalerw;
        $y = $y * $scalerh;

        imagecopyresampled($img_base, $img,0,0,$x1,$y,$x2 * 2,$y2 * 2, $width, $height);

        $path_info = pathinfo($path);    
        switch ($path_info['extension']) {
            case "gif":
                imagegif($img_base, $path);  
            break;
            case "jpeg":
                imagejpeg($img_base, $path);  
                break;
            case "png":
                imagepng($img_base, $path);  
                break;
            case "jpg":
                imagejpeg($img_base,$path);
                break;
        }
       imagedestroy($img_base);
    }
```

**Explanation** of the variables:

- `$path` = The path to the file, so make a loop from all the images.
- `$x1`   = The x coordinate of the part of the image you want to select.
- `$y1`   = The y coordinate of the part of the image you want to select.
- `$w`    = The width of the part of the image you want to select.
- `$h`    = The height of the part of the image you want to select.
- `$x2`   = Width of the original image
- `$y2`   = Height of the original image

[image]

So you can basically select a box like that, from the original image. But, then with `php`.

**How to change save path:**

You can change the path to where it saves very easily, in the last part of the code you see the `imagegif` or any of the other in the `switch` statement. You see the variable `$path` there, that is where it saves ( in this case exactly where if found the image ). That way you can exactly save it to where you want.

I hope this all makes sense, further questions, please don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: @Nick I have edited my answer, I hope this comes close what you are trying to achieve. As @SeweitHotroyman mentioned, there are functions within `wordpress` that are able to do this. A plus when putting a bit of time into this, it will work anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

Couldn't you use the **add_attachment** and **edit_attachment** actions, fired after the image's been saved, to make your thumbnail and save it where you wish?

```
add_action('add_attachment', 'theme_attachment_handler', 999);
add_action('edit_attachment', 'theme_attachment_handler', 999);
...
function theme_attachment_handler($attachment_id) {

    $image = wp_get_image_editor( $metadata['file'] );
    if ( ! is_wp_error( $image ) ) {
        $image->resize( 300, 300, true );
        $image->save( 'newpath/new_image.jpg' );
    }
    // Note you can get all the sizes here too, and cleanup:
    $metadata = wp_get_attachment_metadata($attachment_id);
    if(!empty($metadata['sizes'])) {
        foreach($metadata['sizes'] as $size_name => $size_info) {
            // delete, move, ....
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

u can use this plugin [Imsanity](https://wordpress.org/plugins/imsanity/) or [resize image](https://wordpress.org/plugins/resize-image-after-upload/)
You can be to learn workings of the Plugin

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not after a plugin to resize the images, as the are already being resized or i can easily use the built-in WordPress functions for that. I need to be able to not renaming them and move them into my folder once they are uploaded

Comment: check on [site][1] and [this][2]
. Wordpress already provides several functions that you want

  [1]: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/
  [2]: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/files/wp-includes/media.php/